# Creation of new record simultaneously in several tables (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a problem of adding new records to my Access database (2010). I have tried almost all possible options, but nothing seems to work out: macro after update, running several append queries at the same time, etc. etc. ...
The point is that already pretty much work is put into this database, but I cannot find a solution on such a simple (and vitally important) thing as adding a new record.

The relationships are as follows (one-to-one) in 5 basic tables:
Employees
Documents
Salaries
Holidays
Appendixes

Everything is tied up by the field of Name, Surname - what I want actually to add.

How may I add new workers in my database?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated, because I have reached a dead-end already.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your relationships between the tables are *all* one-to-one?

Comment: Are you doing this from a form?  Which table are you trying to add to?

Comment: Yes, all are one-to-one. Recently I have tried to leave Name, Surname as a primary key only in Employess table and in others set as primary key ID. So the relationships were changed to one-to-many. But it did not help.

Yes, firstly I was trying to do it from the form, to add Name, Surname into the Employees. Then tried to add though the table, it did not help as well.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the relationships go from the central table - Employees. From this table's field Name, Surname go all further relationship to each table mentioned before. I would love to paste the scheme, but unfortunately I am not able to do that.